# ACF Wordpress - relations - Other publications assigned to the same article

Tags: wordpress, relationship, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have a problem that I have publications that are assigned to articles and I need to display other publications that are assigned to given articles on the details of a given publication.

Each publication can be assigned to several articles and you need to download the 5 latest publications that are assigned to at least one of the same article.

The relationship is made by ACF, as a relationship from the publication to the article via the custom field "related_articles".

Unfortunately, this code does not return any publications. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
$related_articles = get_field('related_articles');

$args_related_publications = array(
  'post_type' => 'publications', 
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'key' => 'related_articles',
      'value' => $related_articles,
      'compare' => 'IN',    
    ),
  ),
);

$related_publications_query = new WP_Query($args_related_publications);
```

Answer (score 0):

We managed to arrange with the client that he would select related publications himself, omitting the articles, so the topic is no longer relevant

Comment: Hi. A coding question was posted seeking an answer related to coding (code was posted). The answer does not address coding; it addresses the workflow with a client. Future visitors to your question will be seeking a coding solution and not find one. Since the question is no longer relevant, and the answer will not be relevant to future visitors please consider deleting the question.